# Setting up cloudflare records to point to AWS global accelerator?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloudflare, amazon-elb, aws-global-accelerator

I set up a global accelerator in front of an ELB for EC2 instance. Accelerator gave me 2 static IP to use for DNS. Currently my DNS A record points to my EC2 public IP. When I remove this record and added the 2 A record with the GA IP's I get a 522 error on the site. What am I doing wrong? AWS support said all should be good and I should ask cloudflare support which is awful and refer me back to AWS. now what?

Comment: Is your ELB inside public subnets?

Comment: @jellycsc yes inside public subnet and health checks are good

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add a CNAME on Cloudflare to the AWS Global Accelerator. In addition set SSL to "flexible" in Cloudflare Page Rules for the entire domain/subdomain if your Origin server isn't setup for 443/SSL.